# How to make an only image button?

Tags: html, css, button, svg, icons

I want to make a button like the notification button in facebook or like the one here in stackoverflow for the recent inbox messages. Is it an icon font inside a button or SVG ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always inspect the element. Looking at the stackoverflow button here for recent inbox messages, it's just an a tag with a background-image of the icon.